# Using JavaScript to get different behavior depending on page size

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to activate different settings for different screen/browser resolutions based on a bit of JavaScript that offers zoom functionality. I've included the below script within my HTML document but I don't think its working correctly.

What I'm saying is if the screen width is more than 1025px AND the width of the browser is greater than 1025px then change `zoomWidth` and `zoomHeight` values.

Where am I going wrong with my IF statement?

```
<script>

if (screen.width >= 1025 && (document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 1025)) {
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $('.jqzoom').jqzoom({
    zoomWidth: 609,
    zoomHeight:756
    });

 });
}

// Start second IF statement

if (screen.width < 1024 && document.documentElement.clientWidth < 1024) {
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.jqzoom').jqzoom({
zoomWidth: 200,
zoomHeight:200
});

});
}
</script>
```

Comment: You might want to look into [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com) if you haven't already.

Comment: `screen.width` is the width of the screen, and `document.documentElement.clientWidth` is the width of the browser client's document. If you're on a desktop, these will not be equal unless your browser is maximized.

Comment: @rgthree I'm not talking maximised though i'm talking: Render these JS lines if the screen width and browser width are larger than 1025px so anything above it.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. You write, "I don't think its working correctly"; could you elaborate on that? What makes you think it's not working?

Comment: @ruakh Well I have two IF statements in my HTML file, one to target 1025px (and larger) screen resolutions and one to target resolutions less than 1024px. I've updated the code to document this. Basically nothing happens when I resize my browser, which leads me to assume my IF statement is wrong.

Comment: The if statement gets executed once. It checks the size when the page is loaded, not when the page is resized. You'll need to add a resize handler to have it execute multiple times.

Comment: The 'if' statements only execute once on page load. When you resize your browser, they've already been executed and don't execute again.

Comment: This has nothing to do with media queries; editing question to remove references to them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The 'if' statements only execute once on page load. When you resize your browser, they've already been executed and don't execute again.

Use jQuery's resize handler to detect a resize:

```
 function checkWidth() {
    if (screen.width >= 1025 && (document.documentElement.clientWidth >= 1025)) {
        $('.jqzoom').jqzoom({ zoomWidth: 609, zoomHeight: 756 });
    }

    if (screen.width < 1024 && document.documentElement.clientWidth < 1024) {
        $('.jqzoom').jqzoom({ zoomWidth: 200, zoomHeight: 200 });
    }
}
$(document).ready(checkWidth);
$(document).resize(checkWidth);
```

Comment: @egr103 yes that's the reason there's the `$(document).ready` line in addition to the `$(document).resize` line.